# eclipse debug サンプル Hello World

Tags: spresense

eclipse+openocdのデバッグ環境を構築中なのですが、
exampleのhelloプログラムのデバッグ方法が分かりません。
手順を具体的に教えていただけないでしょうか?

こちらで、試したのは、nuttxのデバッグを開始したところで、
hello_main()にブレークポイントをはり、
nuttxをコンティニューで実行したのち、
シリアルターミナルから"hello"と入力しました。
結果、セグメンテーションフォルトが発生してコネクションが切れました。

以下は、デバッグコンソールのログとシリアルターミナルのログです。

```
[console]
b hello_main
Breakpoint 2 at 0xd008098: file hello_main.c, line 56.

bt
#0  __start () at chip/cxd56_start.c:277

b
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x28.
Breakpoint 3 at 0x28

c
c
Continuing.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Remote connection closed
-----------------------------------
[serial terminal]
Waiting for debugger connection..                                               
NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-7.22                                                      
nsh> hello                                                              
------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

お世話になっております。自己解決しました、ありがとうございます。

./spresense-openocd/src/rtos/nuttx_header.h
上記、ファイルを修正しました。以下はdiffです。

```
diff nuttx_header.org.h nuttx_header.h
38,40c38,40
< #define XCPREG  0x70
< #define STATE 0x19
< #define NAME 0xb8
---
> #define XCPREG  0x78
> #define STATE 0x1a
> #define NAME 0x14c
```

以上、宜しくお願い致します。